# Vector2 assignment to Vector2Int in TypeScript, how to avoid that?

Tags: typescript, oop, game-development

```
class Vector2 {
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Vector2Int extends Vector2 {
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        if (!(Number.isInteger(x) && Number.isInteger(y))) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        super(x, y);
    }
}

function printVector2Int(vector2Int: Vector2Int) {
    console.log(vector2Int);
}

printVector2Int(new Vector2(0.5, 0.5));
```

I understand that if this code were written in **Java**, it wouldn't work because **Vector2Int** is a **Vector2**, but the inverse is not true. I also understand that it works in **TypeScript** because **Vector2** types satisfy **Vector2Int** types.

How to enforce types to work like in an **Object Oriented** language? Would that be a good use of **TypeScript**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the interfaces differ somehow. And, I realize, that this is a bit odd because there is no integer type, only `number`.

There are a lot of ways to do this.

You could use a private field:

```
class Vector2Int extends Vector2 {
    private valuesAreIntegers = true
    //...
}
```

This will add a private `valuesAreIntegers` proper to each instance. And to be a `Vector2Int` that property must exist.

But this creates a value on each instance that has no use other than to the type.

So you could use `declare` which provides type information but does not *emit* any code.

```
class Vector2Int extends Vector2 {
    declare private valuesAreIntegers
    //...
}
```

Now the type of `Vector2Int` has this extra property, but it never exists at runtime.

---

However, if this class ever has methods it's parent class does not, that will work too:

```
class Vector2Int extends Vector2 {
    //...
    bitwiseAnd(): number {
      return this.x & this.y
    }
}
```

So this "problem" may solve itself if you add any methods to the child class.

Any of these approaches should make the assignment fail as you expect:

```
function printVector2Int(vector2Int: Vector2Int) {
    console.log(vector2Int);
}

printVector2Int(new Vector2Int(0.5, 0.5)); // fine
printVector2Int(new Vector2(0.5, 0.5)); // type error
```

Comment: Thanks @alex-wayne! Yesterday I found out the solution for this problem and it is similar to what you posted. I was not using the `declare` keyword before and because of that my JSON strings were screwed up. I will post the final solution

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the final code after @alex-wayne's solution:

```
class Vector2 {
    declare private vector2;

    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Vector2Int extends Vector2 {
    declare private vector2Int;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        if (!(Number.isInteger(x) && Number.isInteger(y))) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        super(x, y);
    }
}

function printVector2Int(vector2Int: Vector2Int) {
    console.log(vector2Int);
}

printVector2Int(new Vector2(0.5, 0.5));
```

This way, the assignment will work like a Java / C# class! Nice!